# Doing scatterplots, numeric distribution based on factorial value of a column

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, boxplot, anova

I have some data here for which I wish to make a scatterplot.

```
Filename Consonant     V1.dn     C2.dn     V2.dn
1    AK_baagge.TextGrid  Geminate 15.799430 11.422561 12.917102
2     AK_baagi.TextGrid Singleton 15.873483 15.103859 10.125358
3      AK_boli.TextGrid Singleton 15.516522  7.989851 16.906061
4     AK_bolli.TextGrid  Geminate 12.239975 12.350245 12.543218
5     AK_buute.TextGrid Singleton 12.807359 10.062925 14.141459
6    AK_buutte.TextGrid  Geminate 13.920380 22.792710 15.604265
7   AK_chaakki.TextGrid  Geminate 12.182685 18.074965  9.077295
8     AK_gaana.TextGrid Singleton 15.362712  5.532339 15.252506
9    AK_gaanna.TextGrid  Geminate 11.991611 12.869568 12.227161
10   AK_jaaddi.TextGrid  Geminate 11.771755 14.523685 12.019280
11    AK_jaadi.TextGrid Singleton 16.245574  9.477126 12.433014
12   AK_khaane.TextGrid Singleton 14.212490  6.843051 12.272372
13  AK_khaanne.TextGrid  Geminate  9.257361 13.257455  9.714515
16    AK_saami.TextGrid Singleton 15.202102  8.443779 10.259451
17     AK_topa.TextGrid Singleton 10.041053 15.404328 14.443669
18    AK_toppa.TextGrid  Geminate 11.598586 12.701031 19.018746
19   DS_baagge.TextGrid  Geminate 11.274895 12.771750 10.222571
20    DS_baagi.TextGrid Singleton 11.612519 13.455866  7.524220
21     DS_boli.TextGrid Singleton  9.545193  6.328078 11.476345
22    DS_bolli.TextGrid  Geminate 10.285957 11.655632 12.626671
25  DS_chaakki.TextGrid  Geminate  9.997374 18.529020  6.859331
26   DS_chaaku.TextGrid Singleton  9.786320 17.808986  5.777550
27    DS_gaana.TextGrid Singleton 10.602730  4.301289 11.286482
28   DS_gaanna.TextGrid  Geminate 10.698212 12.289987 12.931633
29   DS_jaaddi.TextGrid  Geminate 11.728001 13.249137  7.776028
30    DS_jaadi.TextGrid Singleton 13.573731  6.181932  9.115517
```

How should I code in order to make a scatterplot like the one attached here? [image: Expected output]

Vowel duration and Consonant duration in the picture can be taken synonymous to 'V1.dn' and 'C2.dn' columns in the presented data respectively.

I tried,

```
plot(x= a $C2.dn, y= a $V1.dn, xlab= V1.dn, ylab = C2.dn)
```

but it doesn't give me a sensible result (due to the missing 'Consonant' type)

In terms of variance, it can be imagined this way:

```
anova1<- aov (V1.dn ~ Consonant, data = a)
```

PS I know, posting pictures is discouraged here but the expected plot is
reproduced from elsewhere (Zirak and Skaer, 2014).

Comment: Just a note: posting pictures of code or data is discouraged, but an image of a data visualization can be very helpful, especially if you haven't managed to produce something close with your code.

Comment: Also, can you clarify what you mean about variance? A scatter plot shows the actual datapoints, so unless you're adding some summary stastic to the plot, the variance is explicitly displayed as the individual datapoints and doesn't need to be calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a potential plotting solution using {ggplot2}. If you wanted to map the color or transparency of each point to some other variable such as `V2.dn` similar to the image you shared, you could for example add `alpha = V2.dn` inside the `aes()` of `geom_point()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

a <- read.table(header = T, text = "Filename Consonant     V1.dn     C2.dn     V2.dn
           1    AK_baagge.TextGrid  Geminate 15.799430 11.422561 12.917102
           2     AK_baagi.TextGrid Singleton 15.873483 15.103859 10.125358
           3      AK_boli.TextGrid Singleton 15.516522  7.989851 16.906061
           4     AK_bolli.TextGrid  Geminate 12.239975 12.350245 12.543218
           5     AK_buute.TextGrid Singleton 12.807359 10.062925 14.141459
           6    AK_buutte.TextGrid  Geminate 13.920380 22.792710 15.604265
           7   AK_chaakki.TextGrid  Geminate 12.182685 18.074965  9.077295
           8     AK_gaana.TextGrid Singleton 15.362712  5.532339 15.252506
           9    AK_gaanna.TextGrid  Geminate 11.991611 12.869568 12.227161
           10   AK_jaaddi.TextGrid  Geminate 11.771755 14.523685 12.019280
           11    AK_jaadi.TextGrid Singleton 16.245574  9.477126 12.433014
           12   AK_khaane.TextGrid Singleton 14.212490  6.843051 12.272372
           13  AK_khaanne.TextGrid  Geminate  9.257361 13.257455  9.714515
           16    AK_saami.TextGrid Singleton 15.202102  8.443779 10.259451
           17     AK_topa.TextGrid Singleton 10.041053 15.404328 14.443669
           18    AK_toppa.TextGrid  Geminate 11.598586 12.701031 19.018746
           19   DS_baagge.TextGrid  Geminate 11.274895 12.771750 10.222571
           20    DS_baagi.TextGrid Singleton 11.612519 13.455866  7.524220
           21     DS_boli.TextGrid Singleton  9.545193  6.328078 11.476345
           22    DS_bolli.TextGrid  Geminate 10.285957 11.655632 12.626671
           25  DS_chaakki.TextGrid  Geminate  9.997374 18.529020  6.859331
           26   DS_chaaku.TextGrid Singleton  9.786320 17.808986  5.777550
           27    DS_gaana.TextGrid Singleton 10.602730  4.301289 11.286482
           28   DS_gaanna.TextGrid  Geminate 10.698212 12.289987 12.931633
           29   DS_jaaddi.TextGrid  Geminate 11.728001 13.249137  7.776028
           30    DS_jaadi.TextGrid Singleton 13.573731  6.181932  9.115517")

a %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = C2.dn, y = V1.dn)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = Consonant)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>